# c++ - range v3 - use split_when instead of chunk_by

Tags: c++, range-v3

I need a clean way to replace the construct below:

```
auto v1 = a_container | ::ranges::views::chunk_by( lambda_chunk ) | ::ranges::views::filter( lambda_filter );

for (auto &e : v1) {
 // access the chunk with e.front() and e.back() enabled
}
```

with

```
auto v2 = a_container | ::ranges::views::split_when(lambda_split);
for (auto &e : v2) {
 // how to access the chunk size here?
}
```

the first option gives me a nice delimited chunk (range of ranges), with a size for each chunk, but I cannot extract the size of each chunk for the later.

How to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well..
After trying for hours, and navigating the source code, I found that

```
::ranges::distance(e);
```

does the job..